# How to visually freeform select and save the part of an image in linux without gimp?

Tags: images

Pretty much as per title: How to visually **freeform select** and save the part of an image in linux without gimp?

In other words how do you **freeform** select/cut out something from an image and save this cutout/selection. **Not cropping, nor cli**

[image]

Comment: Can you give us much more information? Within what do you need to do this, for what purpose, what's the input data type, where is it from, save it how, do you know a programming language you want to use to integrate this into something bigger...

Comment: You mean take a screenshot?

Comment: The feature you're looking for is called "cropping" and is available in most image editor software and even some image viewers such as gwenview.

Comment: As per above comment, start sereenshot type app and select area you want to extract and save it.